# Перевод из одной системы счисления в другую

Tags: алгоритм

**Первая ситуация**.

Нужно перевести десятичную дробь например(`0,65`), в двоичную систему счисления!
На примере дроби `0,75` все выходит просто: `0,75 *2 = 1,50 * 2 = 3,00` в итоге получаем `0,11` - получили единицу, и на этом останавливаемся! А в примере `0,65` уже сложнее... тут мы получаем бесконечный цикл, который может продолжаться бесконечно!

Т.е получается `0,65*2 = 1,30 * 2 = 0,60 * 2 = 1,22 * 2 = 0,44 * 2 = 0,88` и тут начинается цикл! Т.е `1,76 -> 1,52 -> 1,04 -> 0,08 -> 0,16 -> 0,32 -> 0,64 -> 1,28 -> 0,46 -> 0,72 -> 1,44` и опять получается `0,88`.

Как понять что мы получили необходимую точность вычислений?

**И вторая ситуация.**

`101101 = 1х2^0 + 0х2^1 + 1х2^2 + 1х2^3 + 0х2^4 + 1х2^5 = 0 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 32 = 46`
// хотя должно получится 45

проверяем
`46/2 = 23 -> 46 - 46 = 0`
`23/2 = 11 -> 23 - 22 = 1`
`11/2 = 5 -> 11 - 10 = 1`
`5/2 = 2 -> 5 - 4 = 1`
`2/2 = 1 -> 2 - 2 = 0`
`1`
и получается `101110` совсем другое число!

**Что я не так выполнил?**

Answer (score 1):

**В первом случае** Вы сами должны знать, какая необходима точность вычислений.

**Во втором случае** предлагаю Вам переводить, используя разряды. Разряды, как известно, считаются с нуля. Тогда смотрим - в числе **101101** 6 разрядов. Получаем

`1 * 2^5 + 0 * 2^4 + 1 * 2^3 + 1 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^1 + 1 * 2^0 = 45.`

Comment: пока набирал, @yozh уже ответил ;)

Comment: с практическим идентичным ответом :)

Answer (score 0):

Со второй ситуацией ясно: первое слагаемое у вас не 0, а `1*2^0=1`, а второе - `0*2^1=0`. Итого 45.

На счет первой ситуации. Сам я не занимался серьезно дробями в разных системах счисления, но [википедия говорит](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B4_.D0.B8.D0.B7_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.8F.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D0.B2_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.83.D1.8E), что точное приведение возможно в редких случаях, так что вы должны сами решить, какая точность для вас достаточна.

Comment: А блин... забыл что любое число в нулевой степени дает 0!
Спасибо, плюс пока что не могу поставить)

Comment: @Nu3oN, вообще-то любое число в нулевой степени дает 1.

Comment: снова накосячил гг

Comment: любое число кроме нуля, конечно же